# How do I split two columns in two separate tables into joined multiple rows in a view?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, split, sql-server-2012

I have two separate tables, each containing character-separated cells. One table contains all the key data, the other all the val data. In the application, both tables are loaded into recordsets, the two cells are split into two arrays and the arrays are then used 'side-by side' to create key/val pair.

Trying to decouple the database from the application, I will basically create a view that emulates this behavior.

I created some sample tables and data to better illustrate it.

```
/* Create tables */
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblKeys](
    [KeyId] [int] NOT NULL, /*PK*/
    [KeyData] [nvarchar](max) NULL
)
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblValues](
    [ValId] [int] NOT NULL, /*PK*/
    [KeyId] [int] NOT NULL, /*FK*/
    [Language] [nvarchar](5) NOT NULL,
    [ValData] [nvarchar](max) NULL
)

/* Populate tables */
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblKeys] ([KeyId], [KeyData]) VALUES
    (1, '1|2|3'),
    (2, '1|2|3|4'),
    (3, '2|1')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblValues] ([ValId], [KeyId], [Language], [ValData]) VALUES
    (1, 1, 'en',    'Apple|Orange|Pear'),
    (2, 1, 'sv-se', 'Äpple|Apelsin|Päron'),
    (3, 2, 'en',    'Milk|Butter|Cheese|Cream'),
    (4, 2, 'sv-se', 'Mjölk|Smör|Ost|Grädde'),
    (5, 3, 'en',    'Male|Female'),
    (6, 3, 'sv-se', 'Man|Kvinna')
```

The desired end result in the view looks like this:

```
| KeyId | KeyData | Language | ValData
+-------+---------+----------+----------+
|     1 |       1 |       en | Apple    |
|     1 |       2 |       en | Orange   |
|     1 |       3 |       en | Pear     |
|     1 |       1 |    sv-se | Äpple    |
|     1 |       2 |    sv-se | Apelsin  |
|     1 |       3 |    sv-se | Päron    |
...
```

etc.

I've seen similar questions here on StackOverflow, but they all deal with a single table being tilted in similar ways. I need to tilt both tables while using the positions of the data in the two columns KeyData and ValData as siginficants when recombining them into proper key/val pairs.

How would I do this in an efficient manner?

[Edit]: The database design is not mine. It's some old crap I inhereted. I **know** it's bad. Bad as in *horrendous*.

Comment: Don't store data like | separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble. (As you may have noticed today...

Comment: I know. It's legacy crap beyond my control, though. I'm trying to make it bearable to work with. I would never had done ith that way myself.

Comment: Btw: Thx fro the copy'n'pasteable test scenario and the expected output. Worth an upvote

Comment: If you want an answer it's a good thing to provide the best possible input to work with. If you want help, make sure that the helper can focus on the actual problem, not the setup. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work for you. But: **you really should change your data design!**

```
;WITH Splitted AS
(
    SELECT v.Language
          ,v.ValData
          ,v.ValId
          ,k.KeyData
          ,k.KeyId
          ,CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(v.ValData,'|','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS ValData_XML 
          ,CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(k.KeyData,'|','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS KeyData_XML 
    FROM tblValues AS v
    INNER JOIN tblKeys AS k ON v.KeyId=k.KeyId
)
,NumberedValData AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY KeyId,Language ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RowNumber
      ,KeyId
      ,Language
      ,A.B.value('.','varchar(max)') AS ValD 
    FROM Splitted
    CROSS APPLY Splitted.ValData_XML.nodes('/x') AS A(B)
)
,NumberedKeyData AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY KeyId,Language ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RowNumber
      ,KeyId
      ,Language
      ,A.B.value('.','varchar(max)') AS KeyD 
    FROM Splitted
    CROSS APPLY Splitted.KeyData_XML.nodes('/x') AS A(B)
)
,Combined AS
(
    SELECT nk.KeyId
          ,nk.KeyD
          ,nk.Language
          ,nv.ValD
    FROM NumberedKeyData AS nk
    INNER JOIN NumberedValData AS nv ON nk.KeyId=nv.KeyId AND nk.Language=nv.Language AND nk.RowNumber=nv.RowNumber
)
SELECT Combined.KeyId
      ,Combined.KeyD AS KeyData
      ,Splitted.Language  
      ,Combined.ValD AS ValData
FROM Splitted
INNER JOIN Combined ON Splitted.KeyId=Combined.KeyId AND Splitted.Language=Combined.Language
ORDER BY Splitted.KeyId,Splitted.
```

The result

```
KeyId   KeyData Language    ValData
   1    1       en          Apple
   1    2       en          Orange
   1    3       en          Pear
   1    1       sv-se       Äpple
   1    2       sv-se       Apelsin
   1    3       sv-se       Päron
   2    1       en          Milk
   2    2       en          Butter
 [...]
```

Comment: Yes - the database design is crap. Not my call, though. It's a really old homebrew from way back before I were involved with the company. The original database "designer" seems to have had no knowledge about database design whatsoever. From analyzing the database design my guess is that it originated as some business managers Excel spreadsheet that just was ported over into an SQL Server.

Comment: @CBDuRietz, poor Guy :-) Such "legacy crap" can be a night mare... I'll edit my answer to add a `PARTITION BY KeyId,Language ` into the `ROW_NUMBER()`

Comment: I should point out that the original tables involved are even worse. The ones I presented in the question was sanitized and simplified to focus on the problem at hand. :-)

Comment: @CBDuRietz Good luck and happy coding! If you like my answer please vote it up, if it solves your issue please - additionally mark it as accepted answer, thx!

Comment: Seems to work like a charm. I will try to port it back into the real database before I mark it as an accepted answer, though. I might have a followup question or two. The database is a minefield.

Comment: @CBDuRietz, glad to read, that it works for you... If there are followups please consider to start a new question and place a link here.

Comment: Arghhh!
Worked just fine in my sample rig, but the production tables have corrupt data where the Key and Val fields hold different number of data, i.e. KeyData = '1|2|3' & ValData = 'Male|Female'. I need to do some cleanup. I should've known. :-/

Comment: @CBDuRietz You might change the `INNER JOIN` in `Combined` to a `FULL OUTER JOIN` and check for`KeyD` or `ValD` being `NULL` ...

Comment: The error occurs in the first SELECT (splitted) It seems I have some weird values  in the ValData column that makes the cast/reaplce statement go south. I get "illegal name character" or "undeclared entity" in the XML parsing depending on what language I'm filtering on. There are some html code in some of the data that might mess things up.

Comment: @CBDuRietz use replace to change < > and & to &lt; &gt; and &amp;

Comment: Ahh - I tried the &lt; and &gt; but forgot the &amp;. That took care of it. :-)
Thanks, once again.